# Issue wp post meta add

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

Using this line:

```
wp post meta add 525 _price 150.00 --debug
```

Hangs with the following message:

```
Debug: Loaded WordPress (2.308s)
Debug: Running command: post meta add (2.308s)
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was a quote to the meta field:

```
wp post meta add 525 '_price' 150.00
```